# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: Unknown source file : com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/app/BuildConfig;

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-multidex

I am setting up espresso on my build which is going fine except that I need to clean the project every time before I run the tests or i get the following error. Potentially this is a multi-dex problem. Just wondering if there are suggestions as to how to avoid this error without cleaning first as it really slows down the fix & run cycle.

```
Unknown source file : UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    Unknown source file : com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/app/BuildConfig;
    Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really a fix but I have managed to work around this by deleting the app/build/intermediates/dex folder. Then i don't have to clean after each change.